# trying to understand the flow chart of the extended message protocol as mentioned in bep 10

Tags: bittorrent, dht, torrent

I was reading bep 10 and I'm trying to fit the article to the packets I've captured.
essentially through what I understand a client (the initiator) would begin by sending a normal handshake message (as specified in bep 3). Then the receiver will check if the initiator supports the extended protocol, if he does he'll send the extensions he supports using an m dictionary. The initiator then responds with his own m dictionary with his own extensions which matches the responders m dictionary.
How correct is this? Is the only one who can send the extended handshake message first or can the initiator begin with it?

As mentioned above I've read bep 9,10, and 3 (only 10 and 3 matter for this) and I caught packets of extended messages.

Answer (score 1):

The extended message support is negotiated in via reserved bits.
Once a peer learns that both sides support the extension protocol they can send the extended handshake.
Since the send and receive halves of TCP do not operate in lockstep there isn't really any ordering between the extended handshakes, although it will be the receiver who'll usually learn about mutual support a bit sooner and so might end up sending the extended handshake sooner, but they're not required to.

> The initiator then responds with his own m dictionary with his own extensions which matches the responders m dictionary.

No, they're not required to match. They can simply advertise what they can receive. In principle it can make sense for a client to receive some extensions but not send them or vice versa.

Comment: As an initiator that wants to download the metadata using bep 9, after the receiver showed support for the extended protocol how can I send an m dictionary for testing if he supports bep 9?

Comment: You're not saying which part is currently preventing you from sending it.

Comment: sorry, after further inspection i understand. the only question left for now is how is the integer value of the extension in the m dictionary decided? in their example ut_metadata is 3 but in the example i caught its 2. why is that? also does the header of the extension (like ut in here) important to match? and in that case is there a list of headers to use so i could implement the extension i want?